# is there a simple way to list every templates / php files used to generate a specific page?

Tags: php, theme-development, child-theme, customization

To customize a theme , it is not always easy to trace every files that are used and find out which one do what .
For example i' like to find out how my menu is generated so i can add some conditions to it , and also change the display.
Is there a way to find out all the files loaded ? which header is used ...etc...
maybe put a bit of code somewhere  in the autoload sytem? or using firebug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WordPress does not really track what theme files are loaded beyond some basic things (for example `$template` global holds main template file).

You can use PHP's native [`get_included_files()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-included-files.php) to list *all* PHP source files loaded during request and narrow it down to your theme. Note that for more complex themes this will have not only templates, but likely a lot of framework files as well.

Answer (score 1):

There Is no method known to me.
I would suggest you to set yourself apart with the file hierarchy and to learn bit by bit where the functions are written.

And use [the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/) to search for functions.
It can give you information about the file in which your desired function is included.